# python-xml: Not well-formed (invalid token) - xml.etree utf mode

Tags: python, elementtree, parsexml

I have following XML file structure:

```
<doc id="4611827073121129112">
<class name="tag:September_11" val="-0.079590" />
<class name="tag:Theater" val="-0.134223" />
<class name="tag:Adaptation" val="-0.106678" />
<class name="tag:Paranormal" val="-0.183504" />
<class name="tag:Magic" val="-0.179214" />
<class name="tag:Comedy_Drama" val="-0.044658" />
<class name="tag:Fashion" val="-0.280695" />
<class name="tag:Running" val="0.160316" />
<class name="tag:Construction" val="-0.072044" />
<class name="tag:Suspense_Thriller" val="-0.370302" />
<class name="tag:Space" val="-0.239723" />
<class name="tag:Police" val="-0.139019" />
<class name="tag:Hip-Hop_&_Rap_Music" val="-0.290353" />
<class name="tag:Surfing" val="-0.027105" />
<class name="tag:Halloween" val="-0.236606" />
<class name="tag:Mystery_&_Suspense" val="0.005384" />
<class name="tag:Educational" val="-0.166370" />
<class name="tag:Biography" val="-0.126149" />
<class name="tag:Religion" val="-0.034275" />
<class name="tag:Cartoon" val="-0.487169" />
<class name="tag:Auto_Racing" val="-0.047648" />
<class name="tag:Pets" val="-0.118809" />
</doc>
```

file doesn't have xml extension for example file name is `test.values`

to try out first I decided to use python shell: I am using Anaconda version version of python:

```
Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 15 2014, 10:37:34)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org

>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.parse('test.values')
```

I am getting following error:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 14, column 43
```

After close look at the line:

```
<class name="tag:Hip-Hop_&_Rap_Music" val="-0.290353" />
```

I realize it has `&` and I some what guessed was thet xml.etree package doesn't open the file in utf mode:

I manually delete `&` and things work fine. But problem is that I have to read large amount of files and parse. Based on my google search I couldn't find any examples that shows `etree` package opening files in `utf-8` mode. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You're right that it's the &, but not that it has to do with Unicode (though perhaps Unicode issues could come up after you solve this one.

You can't have ampersand or less-than inside an attribute value in XML, unless you escape it (as &amp; or &lt; respectively). So whatever program wrote the XML should be fixed to detect and re-code those characters.

Comment: These are data dumps from 3rd party so its pretty much impossible to change the originating code. I guess I have to read line by line and strip those characters.

Comment: re.sub(r'&', '&amp;', s)